# How to apply style by Id for element when using ::ng-deep selector

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, css-selectors

I have two `checkbox` of `angular-material`. I want to apply different style for both `checkbox` using  `::ng-deep` selector.

This is my code

```
<section class="example-section">
<mat-checkbox id=" #matCh" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox id=" #matCh2"  class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="indeterminate">Indeterminate</mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

This is style

```
<style id="matCh">
 ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
  } 
  
 ::ng-deep
   .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>


<style id="matCh2">
  ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
     background-color: green;
   } 
   
  ::ng-deep
    .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
     background-color:green;
   }
 </style>
```

I tried this way too but shows `green` color only

```
<style>
 #matCh ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
  } 
  
 #matCh ::ng-deep
   .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

It always shows `green` color both `checkbox` not `red`. How can I fix this

Comment: i noticed that in your `<mat-checkbox id=" #matCh"` there is a space before the `#`. You don't have to put `#` in your ID. `#` is being used by the css selector to refer the ID of html element.

So you might want to try: 
`<mat-checkbox id="matCh"  ........` and `<mat-checkbox id="matCh2"  ........`

Also, i'm just wondering how did you put the style in. Is it in a separate classes or is it inline in the `.ts` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxgcrb?file=src/app/checkbox-configurable-example.css

You have to use different css class to identify. Why always getting green color in your because this last css which override above one due to lack of unique identifier in both checkbox.

**html** :

```
<section class="example-section">
<mat-checkbox id="#matCh"   class="example-margin firstone" [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox id="#matCh2"    class="example-margin secondone" [(ngModel)]="indeterminate">Indeterminate</mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

css :

```css
::ng-deep .firstone.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.firstone.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
}
::ng-deep .firstone .mat-checkbox-background,
.firstone.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
}
::ng-deep .secondone.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: green;
}
::ng-deep .secondone .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Even you can use `id` as unique indentifier as said in above comment. remove space in your `id` and # and use like :

```css
::ng-deep #matCh.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
#matCh.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
}
::ng-deep #matCh .mat-checkbox-background,
#matCh.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: red;
}
::ng-deep #matCh2.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: green;
}
::ng-deep #matCh2 .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: green;
}
```